# Assign explicit version to existing rows of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where records are inserted and updated. In case of updates, a new row is inserted into the table. In order to track updates for a given record, there's a column added to the table called `root_record_id` which holds the id of the very first record in the update chain.

For eg: Consider the record table schema as follows:

| id | root_record_id | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 1 | ... |
| 5 | 2 | ... |

In this case, a record with id=1 was inserted, which was then updated to id=3 and then to id=4. Similarly the record with id=2 was inserted and then updated to id=5.

I want to add a version column to this table, where version is incremented on each update and starts with 0.

| id | root_record_id | version | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | ... |

I tried writing queries using group by clause on `root_record_id` but failed to accomplish the task.

Comment: Do you want a query that generates the version number for a single result set or are you asking how to implement this as a trigger or cumputed column or in your isnert/update logic?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using SQL Server. Added the tag.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I want to add a new column and in order to perform the migration, I want to design the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the general sequence on how to add the column and then pre-fill the values, then follow this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a04b49fbda3883a9605f5482e252a1b

1. Add the `version` column allowing nulls:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Records ADD version int null;
   ```
2. Update the `version` according to your logic:

   ```
   UPDATE Records
   SET version = lkp.version
   FROM Records r
   INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Id, COUNT(root_record_id) OVER (partition by root_record_id ORDER BY id ASC)-1 as version
       FROM Records
   ) lkp ON r.Id = lkp.Id;
   ```
3. Alter the `version` column to *NOT* allow nulls

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Records ALTER COLUMN version int not null;
   ```
4. Finally, ensure that you increment the version column during new row inserts.

Comment: I think your INNER JOIN needs a WHERE clause to limit it to records with an ID <= the outer Records ID.

Comment: @AaronReese that's not how it works, yes that would help for a `CROSS APPLY` that evaluates for each row, but in this case we want a set based operation.

Answer (score 1):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b61bdd9fbd0c7939b7bfb1bb75df2b15)

This query produces the **version** that you can use (in an update, or in a trigger):

```
SELECT
    id,
    root_record_id,
    RANK() OVER (partition by root_record_id ORDER BY id ASC)-1 version
FROM table1
ORDER BY id;
```

output:

| id | root_record_id | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: I would have used `COUNT()` but the result is pretty much the same: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8e81168a44884d3c3ccc47f7252769e

Comment: There are multiple roads that lead to Rome ...